# vs-select from vuesax not working and duplicate root node in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm working with vuejs 2.5.16, vuesax 3.5.7 and webpack template from vue-cli. When i utilize a vs-select component im my form, the options are not visible, the list size seems to be correct, but the values are all null. And in the Dev Tools the root node gets doubled.
Any sugestions?

```
<vs-col vs-w="2">
<label for="sexo">Sexo</label>
<vs-select v-model="pessoa.sexo">
    <vs-select-item v-bind:value="opt.value" 
       v-bind:text="opt.text" v-bind:key="index"
       v-for="(opt, index) in sexo_opt"/>
</vs-select>
```

```
data(){
    return{
       pessoa.sexo:'M',
       sexo_opt: [{text:'Masculino',value:'M'},{text:'Feminino',value:'F'}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because pessoa.sexo isn't a valid object key, the dot is not allowed, if you type in your console

```
var a = {name:"tom",user.friends:3}
```

you'll get

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

now..you can change this to just pessoa or use a nested object and you can access to it as pessoa.sexo

```
pessoa : {sexo : "M"}
```

I hope I helped you..